# Two elements in section .data

Tags: nasm

I've been trying to do the puts function from the libc in asm, and I have been struggling with this: if the argument passed to puts is null then it should write "(null)\n" to the standard output, else it should write the string + \n.

At first I tried to declare two elements in my section .data like so :

```
 int    puts(char *s);

 section .data
    nl db 10
    null_msg db "(null)", 10

 section .text
    global _ft_puts

 _ft_puts:
 mov        rax, rdi
 cmp        rdi, 0
 jz     nul
 xor        r9, r9
 jmp        len

len:
   cmp      byte[rdi + r9], 0
   jz       write
   inc      r9
   jmp      len

write:
   mov      rax, 0x2000004
   mov      rsi, rdi
   mov      rdi, 1
   mov      rdx, r9
   syscall
   mov      rax, 0x2000004
   lea      rsi, [rel nl]
   mov      rdi, 1
   mov      rdx, 1
   syscall
   jmp      return

nul:
   mov      rax, 0x2000004
   mov      rdi, 1
   lea      rsi, [rel null_msg]
   mov      rdx, 7
   syscall
   jmp      return

return:
   mov      rax, 1
   ret
```

It didn't print any error, but only the null_msg was printed. Anyway I found a workaround by using the \n from the null_msg but still I remain curious. I am using NASM version 2.11.08 compiled on Mar 10 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known bug ([here](http://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392306) and [here](http://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392308)) in 2.11.08 to do with relative addressing combined with multiple entries in the data section, at least on OSX Yosemite (I gather you're using OSX since your `syscall` numbers use the OSX class-syscall 'standard').

I'd try testing the same code with an earlier release of `nasm` and, if it works, that's probably where your issue lies.

It might also be worthwhile having a look at the generated assembler code to see what it's *actually* producing, since that (rather than your source code, unfortunately) is what the CPU will be executing. One symptom I've seen is that it uses an incorrect fixed offset when loading the data item or address.